# How to avoid `beamer` to print its title page?

Tags: beamer, titles

It is the first time I am using `beamer` and I am trying to make a title page as I would do in a `book` class, but apparently `beamer` forces its own title page to be printed before mine. I have no `\author` or `\title` specified, so basically it just prints a blank page with `\today`.

I nested my title page within `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` as I would do in any other document class. A MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
My title page
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

How can I force `beamer` to print **only my** title page?

Comment: Just don't use `\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}` if you don't want `beamer`s title page - does that help? (Use `\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}` instead.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt I am stunned, it works! Was it that simple? Thank you for your comment, why don't you post it as an answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want `beamer`s title page at all, don't use the `titlepage` environment. You can design your own titlepage in a separate frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
My title page
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```